# What does Clojure function #(:jerry @%) means

Tags: clojure

I'm very new in Clojure. I'm learning with help from Clojure Koans. I found an answer with code below:

```
(= ["Real Jerry" "Bizarro Jerry"]
       (do
         (dosync
          (ref-set the-world {})
          (alter the-world assoc :jerry "Real Jerry")
          (alter bizarro-world assoc :jerry "Bizarro Jerry")
          (vec (map #(:jerry @%) [the-world bizarro-world]))))))
```

from: https://github.com/viebel/clojure-koans/blob/master/src/koans/16_refs.clj#L42

It's pretty unfriendly for Google to search like "Clojure @%". So I get nothing from Internet.

*How does it works for the function "#(:jerry @%)"?*

And the code below is the answer from me, but it doesn't work.

```
(= ["Real Jerry" "Bizarro Jerry"]
       (do
         (dosync
          (ref-set the-world {})
          (alter the-world assoc :jerry "Real Jerry")
          (alter bizarro-world assoc :jerry "Bizarro Jerry")
          (vec (map (fn [x] (:jerry x)) [the-world bizarro-world]))
         )))
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`#( ...)` is a [reader macro for anonymous function](https://clojure.org/reference/reader#_dispatch) where `%` means the first argument passed to the function. For example:

`#(println %)`

is equivalent to:

`(fn [x] (println x))`

`@` is a [reader macro for `deref`](https://clojure.org/reference/reader#_deref) so again:

`@some-variable`

is the same as:

`(deref some-variable)`

and is used to dereference a current value from one of the [ref types](https://clojure.org/reference/refs).

Thus `#(:jerry @%)` is an anonymous function which when applied to a ref (e.g. an atom) will `deref` its current value and use it as an argument to call `:jerry` [keyword as a function](https://clojure.org/reference/data_structures#Keywords) with the value.

Comment: Sir, you really make my day!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

`the-world` and `bizarro-world` are "derefable", which means that you can use `@` in front to get their value.

You are using an anonymous function, indicated by `#( )`. In an anonymous function, the percent sign `%` indicates the argument to the function.

So `@%` means, "dereference the argument to this function."

`:jerry` is a keyword used as a function, which gets the value associated with the key `:jerry` in the map.

For example:

```
(def coll [(ref {:jerry 21})
           (ref {:jerry 42})])
=> #'user/coll

(map #(:jerry @%) coll)
=> (21 42)
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides, you could find other "weird" symbols in clojure here .
https://yobriefca.se/blog/2014/05/19/the-weird-and-wonderful-characters-of-clojure/